# Added column but cannot update the new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table `[ops].[Table]` to which I want to:

1. First check if the column name `[ColName]` exists.
2. If it does not, then add the column to the table.
3. Set the default type to decimal, and update all values to be 0.
4. Enforce that the table cannot be nullable.

I've written the following script to achieve this:

```
IF COL_LENGTH ('ops.Table', 'ColName') IS NULL
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [ops].[Table] ADD [ColName] DECIMAL(28,12)
UPDATE [ops].[Table] SET [ColName] = 0
ALTER TABLE [ops].[Table] ALTER COLUMN [ColName] DECIMAL(28,12) NOT NULL;
END
```

The issue I am getting is that in the `UPDATE` statement, SQL tells me that `[ColName]` is an invalid column name.

How would I get around this and what appears to be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing an `UPDATE`, why not set the `DEFAULT` and the `NOT NULL` property in the `ALTER`?

```sql
ALTER TABLE ops.[Table] ADD ColName Decimal(28,12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES;
```